# How to connect a Flow to a Stream in SpinalHDL

Tags: hdl, spinalhdl

I have a write sensitive APB register which shall push into a FIFO with clock domain crossing. I though I would write:

```
val myFlow = Flow(...)
busCtrl.driveFlow(myFlow,address=4)
val myFifo = StreamFifoCC(...)
myFifo.io.push << myFlow
```

But the << operator requires a Stream, so a type error happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
myFifo.io.push << myFlow.toStream
```

Should be fine, if the fifo overflow, the myFlow transaction will be lost